# CSS image-set / background-image. Alternative to img srcset? Does anyone use this?

Tags: image, css, srcset

Just like "srcset" for the html <img> tag, there is a CSS background-image property called "image-set".

W3C Info: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#funcdef-image-set

It is currently compatible with Chrome, Safari, Opera, and Android Browser. Not currently compatible with FireFox or IE / Edge browsers. It appears to be in development for Microsoft's Edge browser as well.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-image-set

Here is an example of the implementation / testing: cloudfour.com/examples/image-set/

It appears to only accept generic (x) resolutions, dpi, for normal vs retina screens.

```
<image-set-option> = [ <image> | <string> ] <resolution>

background-image: image-set( "foo.png" 1x,
                             "foo-2x.png" 2x,
                             "foo-print.png" 600dpi );
```

I can't find any documentation on this beyond this.

**My questions is are:**

Does anyone use this?

Can this be used to optimize for page loading speed (ex. different versions based on screen widths for 320px width, 640px width, 1024px width, etc)?

*(I know about @media screen and (max-width), don't mention this please.)*

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am concerned, it doesn't work at all.
You can see for yourself on [here](https://mellifluous-heliotrope-d11c2e.netlify.app/)
lower the viewport's enough to make sure the header's height goes below 75px, and use the developpers tool's network panel, refreshing with cache.
The background's file has "ruin" in its name. You'll see only the biggest being downloaded.
More precisely, regardless of order of writing the img-set value, only the picture with the "1x" index is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

this is part of image optimization as browser will use the image which it needs rather than shrinking a big image and thus will improve page loading because lesser resolution image will be smaller in size and hence faster to load..

use picturefill to the fullest.. it's a great resource..

Comment: Dhaval, have you used "image-set" before? What are you meaning when you say picturefill?  This https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/ a javascript library for the picture element?

Comment: yes I have used responsive images I have used scottjehl.github.io/picturefill for the same